# Floating with CSS - Is a width required?

Tags: css, css-float

When I was learning CSS some time back I read that when you float elements that a width for each element was required. Is this true?

The reason I ask now is because I wanted to float varying width elements; but obviously this wasn't working as the longer elements would just wrap to the next line. I took out the width for the elements in the CSS & it displays how I want it to..... the elements just take up the space & if it's too long for the width of the container then it will just display on the next line.

Comment: can you give an example ? i can't imagine this.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/changes.html#q58

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Width is not required. It depends entirely on what you're trying to accomplish.

When I float elements with a static width it's usually to create a column-like layout

```
.sidebar { float: left: width: 30%; }
.content { float: left: width: 70%; }
```

but for times when you want items to take up as little space as possible and wrap to the next line, width isn't necessary.

And, as always, when you float, make sure you `clear:both` or `left` or `right`

Comment: If you always set the width and have strict layouts you don't really need to clear anything though, I hardly ever use clear except to fix the ever present Firefox "bug" when content expands.

Answer (score 2):

No. This is not required. A lot of people say you *should*, but it is not by any means required.

Answer (score 2):

A floated element will take up only as much width as it needs. The containing element will shrink or expand to its size.

If you don't float a block level element it will expand to 100% width.

Answer (score 1):

This was true in older browsers such as Firefox 1.0, but it's not true in modern browsers.