# Why width CSS attribute of label doesn't work without float?

Tags: html, css

I'm new in CSS, and I've got one question. I'd like to make a good simple form, and there is the following code:

```
<form>
    <div class="row"><label for="name">Some text field</label><input type="text" name="name" /></div>
    <div class="row"><label for="surname">Some another text field</label><input type="text" name="surname" /></div>
</form>
```

Some CSS code:

```
label {
    float: left;
    width: 230px;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 5px;
}

.row {
    clear: left;
}
```

I copied and pasted this code from some book. I understand floating, clearing, but I don't understand why does "width" attribute work with label (because it inline element) and, in this case, why doesn't "width" work without "float"? Please, make me clear. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776121/floating-with-css-is-a-width-required

Comment: Thanks, but my first question is WHY does "width" work with in-line "label" element?

Comment: Just as width wouldn't work with a `<span>` element. Inline elements, unless explicitly declared as `inline-block` or `block` would not react to `width`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Label element is defaulted to `inline` display mode.

Inline elements don't accept a width property, they will be rendered in the width of their content.

Floated elements on the other hand, are like inline-blocks. they will accept a width property.

By applying a `float` property to an element you are essentially changing it's `display` property to something like (but not exactly) `inline-block`.

Comment: It may *appear* as such but per specification an inline that floats is **block**: [Relationships between 'display', 'position', and 'float'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo) (CSS2.1)

Answer (score 0):

`label` is inline element so it doesn't accept the width. To accept the width of any element it should be either `inline-block` or `block` element. And by setting **float** to any element behaves like this is an `inline-block` element and also another info for you position absolute or fixed also thinks as it is a block level element.

If you want to make `label` accept the width you should define label as `inline-block`.

```
label {
    /*float: left;*/
    display: inline-block;
    width: 230px;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Same comment than for the other answer: float is float and position is position, with consequences on display.